# How to implement RESTful API for Siebel IP16

Tags: rest, siebel

We have recently upgraded our Siebel CRM application from version 8.1.1.11 PS16 ( IP13) to latest Siebel CRM version Innovation Pack 16 and are planning to implement **"RESTful API for Siebel IP16"**

Please help me to understand how to start building RESTful API for Siebel CRM along with some examples if possible.

Regards,
Sombir Sheoran

Answer (score 1):

You will find the best articles on [SiebelHub](http://www.siebelhub.com/main/2016/08/siebel-integration-summer-camp-part-8-rest-api.html), those guys have totally dissected the REST api and have posted working code. Siebel IP16 achieves REST via an additional TomCat server, which converts the REST to SOAP passing it to Siebel. So you need to look at its [installation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E74890_01/books/RestAPI/RestAPI_Start.html) as well.

Comment: Thank you Rajnith for your response.  I have gone through this link some time back and yes it was of basic understanding about RESTful APIs in SIebel. I am looking for some more useful information to better understand this new feature which came bundled with Siebel Ip16 package.